# Logging objects with properties which hold sensitive data (to be hashed)

Tags: c#, .net, logging, .net-4.0, log4net

#### Context

I am in the process of designing the logging functionality of an application.
Looking for an elegant and a good performance-wise solution.
(and of course i won't re-implement the wheel :). I will use a popular logging library - eg Nlog, Serilog...).

#### Requirement

Log **objects** that may contain properties with  **sensitive information**.
Lets assume a class person:

```
class Person {
    string Name { get; set; }
    string SensitiveInfo { get; set; }
}
```

A bad (in my opinion) approach, is to do something like this:

```
logger.Debug($"{person.Name}, {Hash(person.SenstiveInfo)}");
```

Why i find this bad?

1. This is a debug log which (based on the logging level) might not be ever logged. Hence, it is wasting CPU resources for hashing without any need.
2. I would prefer to allow the object to be passed as is (eg: logger.Debug(person) ) instead of forcing the developer to manually break down all object properties.

#### Thoughts so far...

Both of the below approaches require a loggerWrapper which - if possible - i want to avoid:

```
class LoggerWrapper {
    LoggerWrapper (ILogger logger) {
        //store the ILogger
    }
    void Log(object objectToBeLogged, LoggingLevel level) {
        //If logging level is not accepted return
        _logger.Log(objectToBeLogged, level);
    }
}
```

**1. Create an ILoggable interface**

```
interface ILoggable {
    string GetLogValue(HashManager hashManager);
}

class Person: ILoggable {
    string Name { get; set; }
    string SensitiveInfo { get; set; }

    string GetLogValue(HashManager hashManager) {
        string hashedValue = hashManager.Hash(person.SenstiveInfo);
        return $"{person.Name}, {hashedValue}"
    }
}

// Now the LogWrapper.Log will expect an ILoggable, and will use the 'GetLogValue' method
// overriding 'ToString()' is an alternative but it is exposed by the 'object' class, and i fear that is not strict enough/can be forgotten.
```

Concerns with this approach: Too demanding for the developers? Maintainability?

**2. Annotations and reflection**

```
class Person {
    [Loggable]
    string Name { get; set; }
    [Loggable, SensitiveInfo]
    string SensitiveInfo { get; set; }
}

// Now the logWrapper will rely on reflection (i think) and choose what to log/hash
```

Concern with this approach: Performance?

---

Are the above approaches considered bad practices?
Is there a better approach?
Are there any libraries which are already dealing with this?

Comment: I dount there is a "right" answer here, as this tends to be pretty opinion-based. But anyway I wouldn´t bother too much for it, just log **what you need**. Not the entire person of course. If you really notice performance-issues, you may think again, but not before you´re sure those issues are even related to the logger.

Comment: Considering performance your second approach by the way seems even worse then your naive implementation.

Comment: Thank you @HimBromBeere for taking the time to comment. I would like to believe that there is an approach which is not based on personal opinion. For example your 'performance' comment is valid and is leading me away from the second approach. I am just hoping that 'just log what you need' will not be the best i can do.

Comment: What's the point to log hashed sensitive informations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your **second** approach is OK.

I can think of several alternative approaches but they will end up pretty close to what you have with the attribute annotations.
- like keeping some kind of annotation info in external file.
- or create special type like '`SensitiveInfo<T>`' and use it where the hashing must happens, but is almost the same as annotating the properties.

**For the performance part:**
You can create one time structure at the start of your application which scans for all types in the assemblies. The structure can be dictionary having the name of the type as key (`"MyCompany.App.Core.Person"`) and for the value you can have [`Func`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.func-2?view=netframework-4.8) object created from [dynamically compiled lambda expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expression-1.compile?view=netframework-4.8) which will return the logging message with the hashed values where needed. (this will be the hard part).
**Important Note**:
The jit compiler won't load a dll until is needed so tring to create this structure at the very begging of the startup can skip some of the assemblies. As alternative approach you can try to populate the structure on demand (lazy) as part of the logger wrapper.

Then i will go with logging wrapper which will use the structure to create the logging message for the specific object.

**Some advice:**
1. Logging too much info is not necessary a bad thing - so i would not use the [`Loggable`] attribute - just log everything from the object. This way the overhead for the developer will be minimal. Sometimes you can have very long strings in your object which are not important then you can introduce [`NonLoggable`] attribute.
2. You will probably going to handle hierarchy objects - this will add additional complexity to the creating of the func/labbda expression.

Overall this approach is more complex, but less demanding for the developers.
At the end it depends on what you and your team is willing to do and the amount of work that will be spend/saved (this will depend on the size of the project .. etc).

---

I think the **first approach** will get hard to maintain and add a lot of noise. Logging should be infrastructure concern - automated as much as possible.

Comment: Thank you @vasil, very interesting approach and it satisfies the maintainability/efficiency requirement (good catch on the JIT loading as well :) ). I will PoC it and come back with an update.